# Use a function with dynamic variables

Tags: matlab, loops

I have an array A of size `[m x n]`, a function `f(array, a, b, c)` and an array of variables
`[a1 b1 c1; a2 b2 c2; ... ak bk ck]`.

I want to get an array:

```
[f(A, a1, b1, c1); f(A, a2, b2, c2); ... f(A, ak, bk, ck)]
```

Is it an ellegant way to realize this in MATLAB without using cumbersome loop structure?

```
for i = 1:k
B(i) = f(A, a(i), b(i), c(i));
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html)?
let `P` be the `k` by 3 matrix with parameters `[a1 b1 c1;...' ak bk ck]` then

```
B = arrayfun( @(a,b,c) f( A, a, b, c), P(:,1), P(:,2), P(:,3) );
```

BTW
It is best [not to use `i` as a variable name in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).